# After April 2012 CU manage patch status shows 14.0.6120.5000 but sporadically

Tags: cumulative-update

The installation and config went through fine. But version status in central admin shows 14.0.6120.5000 sporadically. is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking in the list Check product and patch installation status in Central Admin? If so, yes that would be normal, since not all components are upgraded.

Run the following PowerShell command from SharePoint Managment Shell to check the current version:

```
(Get-SPFarm).BuildVersion
```